# Report viewer + rdlc report + export to excel not working in firefox only

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, sql-server-2014, rdlc, reportviewer

i have one issue,

**Before :**
i have one webforms application for reports(**Use ssrs report viewer**)which working fine 
with sql server 2008, and

Reports are display and export to pdf, excel all functionality working fine.

**After :** 
recently i upgrade sql server 2014, now my reports are working properly, only one issue i faced.

All reports are displaying data proper in chrome and export functionality is also working fine, ***but in firefox export to excel not woring***

When i test reports in firefox reports display proper but when i choose option export to excel it returns "about:blank" --> Report not export to excel same functionality is working proper in chrome....

**i have firefox version 54.0 32 bit Windows 7**

Any Suggestion....
i am waiting

Thanks
Chirag

Comment: Does firefox prompt you what to do with the excel file when you click export? Try removing any saved settings for the excel extension (e.g. always save file)

Comment: no, firefox does not prompt what to do with the excel file..
but when i check same report in another pc firefox prompt me to download file and quickly it closed that prompt before i save